# Input Masking in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, masking

I have an input where users are going to type identification numbers and I would like to mask that input so that it always has this format : `XX-XXXXXXXX-X`

The X's can only be numbers and the dashes need to be always in those positions.

Here is what I got so far:

```
import React from "react";
import { Inertia } from "@inertiajs/inertia";
import {useForm, usePage} from "@inertiajs/inertia-react";
import ErrorForm from "./ErrorForm"

function Login() {
    const{data , setData , processing ,reset} = useForm({
        cuit: '',
        password: ''
    })
    const errors = usePage().props.errors

    function submit(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        Inertia.post(route('login'),data,{
            onError:() => reset('password')
        })
    }

    function handleChange(e){
        if(e.target.value.length === 11){
            e.target.value = [e.target.value.slice(0,11),'-'].join('')
        }else if(e.target.value.length >= 2){
            if(!e.target.value.includes('-')){
                e.target.value = [e.target.value.slice(0,2),'-',e.target.value.slice(2)].join('')
            }
        }
        setData('cuit',e.target.value)
    }

    function handleKeyDown(e){
        if(e.key === "0" || e.key === "1" || e.key === "2" || e.key === "3" || e.key === "4" || e.key === "5" || e.key === "6" || e.key === "7" || e.key === "8" || e.key === "9"){
            handleChange(e)
        }
    }
    return(
        <div className="ContenedorLogin">
            <form onSubmit={submit}>
                <input
                    name="cuit"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="C.U.I.T."
                    className="input"
                    onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                    maxLength="13"
                />
                {errors.cuit &&
                    <ErrorForm
                        content={errors.cuit}
                    />
                }
                <input
                    name="password"
                    type="Password"
                    placeholder="Contraseña"
                    className="input"
                    value={data.password}
                    onChange={e => setData('password',e.target.value)}
                />
                <button className="btn-consejo" type="submit" disabled={processing}>INGRESAR</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Login
```

Basically I'm capturing a keyDown event, then changing the input only if the user typed a number and finally in the handleChange function I try to mask and set the value.

It kind of work but not for all cases, for example if I'm in the middle of typing and I already have the first dash and I add a number before the first dash its going to allow it leaving me with something like this : `XXXX-XXXXX`

I imagine I can achieve the result using regular expressions or something like that but I'm not familiar at all with them

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It would work if you bind event on whole input value instead of each key press.

Here, instead of using event **"onKeyDown"**, use **"onChange"**. Also You can use html pattern for accepting number only.

```
<input
    name="cuit"
    type="number"
    pattern="[0-9\/]*"
    placeholder="C.U.I.T."
    className="input"
    onChange={handleChange} // calling handleChange on input change directly
    maxLength="13"
/>
```

You already have working **handleChange()** function, which will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JS to do this use the in-build HTML form validation.

Add a required attribute and a regex pattern to the input. The form won't submit until the input has been validated. And you'll also get little tool-tips to explain what the issue is if you try to submit and the input isn't validated.

In this case the regex reads:

```
^ - start of the value
[0-9]{2}- two numbers followed by a dash
[0-9]{8}- eight numbers followed by a dash
[0-9] - one number
$ - end of the value
```

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {
  
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');
  
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(`Submitted: ${input}`);
  }
  
  function handleChange(e) {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder="dd-dddddddd-d"
        pattern="^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{8}-[0-9]$"
        value={input}
        required
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
input, button { font-size: 1.2em; }
input { padding: 0.3em; }
input:invalid { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```